# ROS Answers SE migration: scripting rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, script, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not know what command line params there are for rviz, but being able to script consecutive runs and record the results would be quite nice (and not so repetitive!). Some examples of things I would like the script to control:

the tf cache buffer size.

the location and orientation of the orbiting camera.

Thoughts? I realize there are a great many rviz params that one might want to control, and it might be cumbersome to code.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11073/scripting-rviz/) by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 682 on 2011-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to `rosrun rviz rviz --help`, the supported command line parameters are:

```
rviz command line options:
-h [ --help ]               Produce this help message
-d [ --display-config ] arg A display config file (.vcg) to load
-t [ --target-frame ] arg   Set the target frame
-f [ --fixed-frame ] arg    Set the fixed frame
-l [ --ogre-log ]           Enable the Ogre.log file (output in cwd)
```

A possibility for setting more options might be to write something like an rviz config file generator since you can load a specific config file via command line parameters. However, I don't think the config file format is documented anywhere.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2011-08-31**:
Thanks, it looks like coding the vcg files is the way to go, it at least resolves the issue of fixing the orbiting camera position (and other viz settings).

**Comment by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on 2013-01-31**:
That --help output is slightly outdated now: the config file extension is ".rviz" as of ROS Groovy.  The Groovy rviz config file format is YAML, and should be pretty easy to generate with Python.